# decode HTML entities in php

Tags: php, entity, decode

I have this string:

```
<p>ëen twéé drïe viêr vijf zes ç   nnneeeeeeggeeeeennn<br></p>
```

after this string goes through multiple applications i end up with the following string:

```
   <p>&Atilde;&laquo;en tw&Atilde;&copy;&Atilde;&copy; dr&Atilde;&macr;e 
   vi&Atilde;&ordf;r vijf zes &Atilde;&sect; &nbsp; nnneeeeeeggeeeeennn<br></p>
```

how do i decode this encoded string back to the original?

I tried:

1. htmlspecialchars_decode(string)

   *This returns:*

   Ã«en twÃ©Ã© drÃ¯e viÃªr vijf zes Ã§   nnneeeeeeggeeeeennn
2. htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode(string));

   *This returns:*

   Ã«en twÃ©Ã© drÃ¯e viÃªr vijf zes Ã§   nnneeeeeeggeeeeennn

**How do i decode this string?**

*PS. I did not know how to describe this problem in the title so feel free to edit my title*

Comment: If something is unclear or you need more information please ask.

Comment: It looks like those `multiple applications` are mesing up your string BER (beyone economic recovery)..... solution is to fix those multiple applications so that they don't corrupt the string n the first place

Answer (score 3):

Use `html_entity_decode($string)` instead.

```
<?php
$str="&Atilde;&laquo;en tw&Atilde;&copy;&Atilde;&copy; dr&Atilde;&macr;evi&Atilde;&ordf;r vijf zes &Atilde;&sect; &nbsp; nnneeeeeeggeeeeennn";
echo html_entity_decode($str);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1). your code however, returns this:
Ã«en twÃ©Ã© drÃ¯eviÃªr vijf zes Ã§   nnneeeeeeggeeeeennn

Comment: Did you set the **charset** in your html doc? (like `<meta charset="UTF-8">` for html5)

Comment: I think this is indeed where i went wrong, thanks to you comments and answer i found the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to answers provided i solved the problem:

i first decode the string with:

```
 html_entity_decode($str),  // thanks Blessed Nerd!
```

then i decode the string with:

```
utf8_decode(); 


$str="Ã«en twÃ©Ã© drÃ¯eviÃªr vijf zes Ã§   nnneeeeeeggeeeeennn";
$string2 = html_entity_decode($str);
echo utf8_decode($string2);
```

output:

ëen twéé drïeviêr vijf zes ç  nnneeeeeeggeeeeennn