# PHP - Convert &#62 and other symbols to text

Tags: php

I have to convert these symbols:

- &#62 ;
- &#9996 ;
- ...

etc.

to:

- >
- ✌

How I can do it? Is anyone function in PHP to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [decode HTML entities in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066638/decode-html-entities-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's `html_entity_decode()` function:

```
<?php
    $str = "&#62;";
    $str = html_entity_decode($str);

    $str1 = "&#9996;";
    $str1 = html_entity_decode($str1);
?>
```

More information at http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php.

**Note:** `html_entity_decode()` function is the opposite of `htmlentities()` function.

Hope this helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "This is some &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; text.";
 echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
 ?>
```

[htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars_decode.asp)