# Decoding too many times encoded string in PHP

Tags: php

I get a string in PHP from an external database which looks like this:

```
$myStr = '&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;br&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;To send a note'
```

As you can see this string is encoded too many times, is there is a way to decode it all the way back using PHP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [decode HTML entities in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066638/decode-html-entities-in-php)

Comment: That looks like bad encoding for a line break or is that just example string?

Comment: Yeah, just noticed too that there's only two valid entities in that string. First `&amp;` and the `&amp;` after the `br`.

Comment: That is the data I get from an external database.

Comment: That data is encoded far too many times. Proper way would be to fix it where ever it's encoded so that would be done only once.

Takes several decodes to get something out of it - https://3v4l.org/8vhZ6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened that your str passed lots of times through `htmlentities()`.

The original string probably was `<br>To send a note`, then, the 1st time it become `&lt;br&gt;To send a note`, the secong it replace all `&` with `&amp;` and so on.

In order to put it inside text area you should to decode it using:

```
<textarea><?php echo html_entity_decode($myStr);  ?></textarea>
```

The code bellow will pass as many times it's necessary to solve your issue:

```
    $modStr = $myStr = '&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;br&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;To send a note';
do {
   $myStr = $modStr;
   $modStr = html_entity_decode($myStr);
} while( $modStr != $myStr );
```

[]s Andrei